# how this variable is not accessed in C?

Tags: c, lint, printf

I have the following code:

```
int number;
char temp[32] = "";


number = snprintf(temp, sizeof(char), "%c", 'A');
```

I made this variable `number` because `snprintf` has a return value, number can remove the warning of `"ignore of return value of snprintf"`, then it gets another lint warning: `Warning 550: Symbol 'number' not accessed`, but I do not need to use the variable `number`, then how to fix it?

And if the `number` is assigned by the return value of snprintf, how could it complain that the `number` is not accessed, how to count it is accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case number receives the bytes printed by `snprintf` and lint is warning about a non used variable, you can skip this lint warning with

`number = snprintf(temp, sizeof(char), "%c", 'A'); /* lint -save -e550 */`

or as others says

```
(void)snprintf(temp, sizeof(char), "%c", 'A');
```

Answer (score 2):

Function got return value to be checked, so use number to check it or do simply like this

```
char temp[32] = "";


if (snprintf(temp, sizeof(char), "%c", 'A') < 0)
  printf("Error occured");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
(void)snprintf(temp, sizeof(char), "%c", 'A');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning that you defined a variable which is not used. In the above sample you assign it a value, but you don't do anything with it. If the variable is really not used, then you can remove it from your code, otherwise write some code that actually uses it, like an `if`, `printf`whatever.

Comment: I made this variable because snprintf has a return value, and variable number can remove the warning of "ignore of return value of snprintf", but it introduce a new warning, how to fix it?

Comment: You can cast snprintf to `void` i.e. `(void)snprintf(temp, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

if you really wants to use number and wants to remove the warning then try this..

```
int number = -1;
char temp[32] = "";


number = snprintf(temp, sizeof(char), "%c", 'A');

if(number <= 0)
{
 /*give some error message */
}
```